# Why URLSession.DataTask.shared is not working properly?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to fetch some quizzes for my application from the server. Unfortunately, it seems that URLSession.DataTask.shared is not working. How do I fix the problem?

This is for Swift 4.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class QuizService {
    let baseUrl = "https://iosquiz.herokuapp.com/api/quizzes"

    func fetchQuizzes(completion: @escaping (([Quiz]?) -> Void)) -> Void {
        if let url = URL(string: baseUrl) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                        if let resultsList = json as? [String: Any], let results = resultsList["quizzes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                            let quizzes = results.map({ json -> Quiz? in
                                print(json)
                                if
                                    let title = json["title"] as? String,
                                    let id = json["id"] as? Int,
                                    let level = json["level"] as? Int,
                                    let description = json["description"] as? String,
                                    let category = json["category"] as? String,
                                    let questions = json["questions"] as? [String: Any],
                                    let imageUrl = json["image"] as? String {
                                    let  quiz=Quiz(id:id,title:title,descript:description,category:category,level:level,imageUrl:imageUrl,questions:questions)
                                    return quiz
                                } else {
                                    return nil
                                }
                            }).filter { $0 != nil } .map { $0! }
                            completion(quizzes)
                        } else {
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }

    }
}
```

My error is that field of quizzes are null, so my code is not working in my view controller.

Comment: Which line exactly are things going wrong?

Comment: FYI - if you can return `nil` inside the `map` transform closure, then you should be using `compactMap`, not `map`.

Comment: let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request)

Comment: And what's wrong with that line exactly?

Comment: It doesnt go along that line, never 'entered', just went to dataTask.resume()

Comment: What you are seeing is correct. The completion block isn't run until you call `resume`. Put a breakpoint on the `if let data = data` line. Run your code. Is the breakpoint hit? Now what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the response here https://iosquiz.herokuapp.com/api/quizzes.

The "questions" should be array of dictionaries instead of dictionary.

so it should works if you replace this line

```
let questions = json["questions"] as? [String: Any]
```

with this line

```
let questions = json["questions"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

BTW, I prefer to extract the logic of parsing json into another method to keep fetchQuizzes method simple.

Hope this helps!